# Как принудительно освободить файл если он занят другим процессом?

Tags: delphi, winapi

Я не знаю каким и нужно что бы старый handle убился и дал доступ к файлу. Что нужно передать в `CreateFile`?

Comment: Если нужно его прочитать, то можно попробовать это сделать через теневую копию. Если записать, то вроде никак, только завершить процесс который его "держит".

Answer (score 0):

Может проще воспользоваться сторонними программами?
В аналогичном вопросе https://superuser.com/questions/335138/how-to-close-all-file-handles-under-a-given-folder-programatically рекомендуют Handle.exe, psfile, unlocker.exe, MalwareByte's FileAssassin, ну и LockHunter, OpenedFilesView

Схожий вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19660879/delphi-get-opened-files-by-process-using-handles